# MySQL PHP Transaction across databases

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I cannot find a definitive answer to whether or not it's allowed to make transactions in PHP span multiple databases.

I am using the same connection object (mysqli) and performing the transaction(s) in this manner:

```
$mysqli->autocommit(false);

try {

    // Assume here that some code would throw an exception

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO db1.x (column) VALUES (y)");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO db2.x (column) VALUES (y)");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    $mysqli->commit();
    // Great success

} catch (Exception $e) {

    $mysqli->rollback();
    throw $e; // handle elsewhere

}
```

Is this allowed and will it properly commit and roll back? According to the manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/xa.html) and other threads on SO, it seems I need to use XA statements, but it's not really clear (to me) if this is when using multiple database servers, multiple connections or just in general when executing above code.

Comment: I would assume if they're on the same DB host machine it would work.

Comment: Well if they were not I could not use the same mysqli object for both statements.

Comment: yes, it'll work, in this particular case. transactions are done per-connection. if you hold open two connections, and start a transaction in each, then you've got two completely separate/different transactions, and actions on one will not affect the other.

Comment: @MarcB - I'm aware of that, and that's why the question specifically states that I'm using the same connection object. If you're sure and can back your claim up feel free to post an answer :)

Comment: It seems like this example already contains almost everything you'd need to verify it.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Haha - yes, but I'm not 100% sure that "does seem to work" is always equal to "you should do it this way and that's the way it's meant to be done" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per comment request above, omitting the create/use feedback:

```
mysql> create database x;
mysql> use x;
mysql> create table x (x int);
mysql> create database y;
mysql> use y;
mysql> create table y (y int);
mysql> start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into x.x values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into y.y values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> rollback;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from x.x;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from y.y;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Note that this is all on a single connection, to a single mysql instance. It will NOT work if the dbs are hosted on different servers, or you're doing each create/insert on different connections.

Comment: I think I'll take your words and this example for it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Transactions apply to the server as a whole. Databases are just used for grouping tables for the purpose of granting permissions (e.g. you can grant permissions to `database.*`) and providing some defaults when creating new tables. And they're used to allow you to select a default database with the `USE` statement, so you don't have to specify the database names on every query.